# ZPL - Set barcode width to fit in label

Tags: barcode, zebra-printers, zpl, barcode-printing

I have the following ZPL code:

```
^XA 
^MMT
^FT450,30^A0,N,10,20^FH\^FDValid Until^FS
^FT435,44^A0,N,13,20^FH\^FD17/02/2037^FS
^FT20,90
^BY1,1,23
^B3N,N,35,N,N
^FD3800231000010087005792152521000235^FS
^FT260,190^A0,N,11,16^FH\^FDSN:  00059 0036712924^FS
^XZ
```

I need to reduce the barcode width, ideally to end where the date start.
Checking online I saw that most of answer suggest to set `^BY1,1`, but still the barcode is too long.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just shrink the size of a barcode. The lines that are 1px wide cannot be shrunk any further.

Seems you are encoding: 3800231000010087005792152521000235. That's quite a bit for a 1D Code 39 barcode. A Code 128 code (`^BC`) is a bit more condensed. Else, try a 2D barcode (like QR or Datamatrix) if you want to encode that much data.

Comment: `[Code 128] (^BC) is denser` especially for digit strings, *if* set to automatic: *^BCN,,N,,**,A*** (or *Subset C* - looks easy to get wrong).